# sftp batch file assistance

Tags: bash, shell, sftp

I have a sftp script and i am trying to connect a sftp directory and copy files into my local machine .I the remote sftp directory i have a file 'note.lst' that file contains the file name's which i need to import from ftp to local directory .

```
 sftp
 cd  /root/ftp1
 lcd /root/foleder1
 cat note.lst > ${2}
 mget ${2}
 bye
```

In the above command line i was trying to cat the list file and move the data of the cat o/p into the variable ${2} and mget them .

The below approach is not working .Can any one help me .

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to use FTP or sftp?

Comment: Here i am using sftp sir !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to break this into two operations:  one to fetch the list, and one to fetch the listed files.

```
# Fetch the list
scratch=$(mktemp -d)
trap "rm -fr $scratch" EXIT
scp user@host:/root/ftp1/note.lst $scratch/filelist.txt
# transmogrigy the list into the SFTP script:
awk 'BEGIN{ print "lcd /root/foleder1"; print "cd /root/ftp1" } { print "get \"" $0 "\"" }' > $scratch/script.sftp
# execute the SFTP script
sftp -b $scratch/script.sftp user@host
```